# If else model not responsive

Tags: r

I am building a model in R and I have a data frame of daily temperature data in Kelvin (.csv file). I will run the model individually for each station. The literature I am basing the model off of states: when the temperature rises above `285.15`, spawning is induced and ER or effective reproduction reserve, is reduced to `0`, meaning my graphical output should fall to zero and start climbing again after the temperature decreases.

[image]

My question is this: How would I write this command into R? 
Thus far I have written:

```
spawn <- ER
spawning <- ifelse(Mussel_Daily_Temp$AS_TEMP > 285.15, 'ER-ER', 0)
```

I have also tried:

```
if(temperature > 285.15) {ER-ER}
```

My parameters look like this:

```
param <- list(Temperature = Mussel_Daily_Temp$AS_TEMP, etc....)
```

Any help would be most appreciated!

Best,

J

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding this correctly but you're just trying to make a flag for when the temperature goes over 285.15? You can do this: `Mussel_Daily_Temp$temp_flag = 0; Mussel_Daily_Temp$temp_flag[Mussel_Daily_Temp$AS_TEMP>285.15] = 1` and that will mark the observations with at least that temperature.

Comment: Its giving me this error: Error in `*tmp*`$Mussel_Daily_Temp : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: Sorry I had to edit it. Are you sure this failed? Mussel_Daily_Temp$AS_TEMP needs to be interpret-able with a > symbol

Comment: It's working! however, I am still confused how it can effect `ER` I am still really new to R and your help is great!!!

Answer (score 2):

Without a data example this is a bit of a challenge...

Right now you are simply creating a 0 for anything at a temp > 285.15

```
spawn <- ER
spawning <- ifelse(Mussel_Daily_Temp$AS_TEMP > 285.15, 'ER-ER', 0)
```

My limited understanding of math says that `ER-ER` will equal zero - so your TRUE or FALSE results in your ifelse statement are both 0.

If you set spawn to the temperature

```
spawn <- ER[Mussel_Daily_Temp$AS_TEMP == 285.15]
```

Then adjust your ifelse statement

```
spawning <- ifelse(Mussel_Daily_Temp$AS_TEMP > 285.15, 'ER-spawn', 0)
```

I think you will get something close to what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, it is returning: `Error in eval(ei, envir) : object ER not found`. ER is part of my state:  `state <- c(E = 0.000124, V = 0.06, ER = 0)`

Comment: again - if you provided actual examples of your data this can be addressed. without it you are on your own.